# Priority of annotations and xml in JPA

Tags: jpa

If you start overwriting a property of an entity in JPA using xml(either in persistence.xml or orm.xml),are all annotations on the given property are ignored.

Are there any exception where the priority of annotations is more than that of xml ?( just like in EJB annotation where one cannot override the transaction type and bean's structural meta data by ejb-jar.xml. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the JPA2 specification from [here](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/). Section **12.2 XML Overriding Rules** describes the rules that apply when the XML descriptor overrides annotations. I'll risk this answer being closed as a link-only answer, but It's a 13 page section that describes each case in detail, so I'm not going to reproduce all of its contents here.